# Edge Browser Thinks User is in Hong Kong

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge, google-search

I'm working with a user where they're using MS Edge to get answers to their questions. When they access google from Edge, it redirects them to `google.com.hk`. Even when they try to search for random things they get results in a different language like below:

[image]

A few things we've tried and checked:

1. VPN is enabled under **Start > Settings >VPN**. I have to check with the admin to see if this is required but found that this could cause this. On my device I have it set `on` as well and google doesn't redirect me.
2. Under **Start > Settings > Time & Language > Region** this is set to `United States` and Regional format is set to `Recommended English (United States)`
3. In **Edge > Settings > Reset Settings**. We reset the browser.
4. Edge browser is on the latest update
5. Cleared browsing data.
6. Under **Start  > Settings  > Privacy > Location** "Allow access to location on this device" is set to `off`.
7. Under **Start > Services > Geolocation service**, we turned this `on`.
8. Only one NIC is on this device and `ipconfig` shows internal IP.

**NOTE**: User mentioned that using google never redirected them in the past. The only thing they know is that this server was updated/rebooted this past week.

Is there anything else that I can check to see why this is happening?

Comment: What you describe isn't a feature of Microsoft Edge.  That is Google doing Geolocation to determine which Google Search you are being served. As for the reason they are being Geolocation to Hong Kong cannot be determined with the information you have provided.

Comment: @Ramhound It probably can be determined because "VPN is enabled...". It only takes a server in HK for Google to do its thing.

Comment: I would just change the region on Google, disable the VPN based out of HK

Comment: @Ramhound The only browser available on the server is Edge. As mentioned, they access google from Edge. I don't see a possible way of changing the region on google from an Edge browser. Unless you've found something out.

Comment: You can change the Region on any Google website.  Google like to autodetect your region through geolocation and the regional settings of your Google account. [Google Search](https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en&fg=1). I am trying to make it clear, Google Search is doing the Geolocation, the region incorrectly being detected and redirected is a Google problem not a Microsoft Edge problem. Google Search is a [web application](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-search) while Microsoft Edge is a browser on Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound got it. I do see the settings now. I also tried https://www.google.com/ncr in the browser and this seems to have 'fixed' the issue for the user. I will try these settings afterwards.